# Retrieving text from Pattern1 to Pattern2 - Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have an input file as below

```
PATTERN1 PTR1 blah blah blah
needThis  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWell  blah blah blah
PATTERN2

PATTERN1 PTR2 blah blah blah
needThis  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWell  blah blah blah
PATTERN2 

............................
............................

PATTERN1  PTRN blah blah
needThis  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWell blah blah blah
PATTERN2
```

I need my function to return only the first column entries from PATTERN1 to PATTERN2 as below,

```
PTR1
needThis thisOneAsWell

PTR2
needThis thisOneAsWell

......................
......................
PTRN
needThis thisOneAsWell
```

PTR1 , PTR2 ...... PTRN are each different texts. PATTERN1 & PATTERN2 are different but consistently present in the file.

How can i achieve this in Python?

I am still a beginner in Python and I am trying to achieve this use re.findall() not getting the desired o/p:

```
def retrieve():
    file = open("fileName","r")
    string = re.findall(r"PATTERN1",file.read())
    print string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest two regexes:

```
txt='''\
PATTERN1 PTR1 blah blah blah
needThis1  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWell1  blah blah blah
PATTERN2

PATTERN1 PTR2 blah blah blah
needThis2  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWell2  blah blah blah
PATTERN2 

............................
............................

PATTERN1  PTRN blah blah
needThisN  blah blah blah
thisOneAsWellN blah blah blah
PATTERN2'''

import re

for m in re.finditer(r'^PATTERN1\s*(.*?)(?=^PATTERN2)', txt, re.M | re.S):
    print re.findall(r'(^\w+)', m.group(1), re.M)
```

Prints:

```
['PTR1', 'needThis1', 'thisOneAsWell1']
['PTR2', 'needThis2', 'thisOneAsWell2']
['PTRN', 'needThisN', 'thisOneAsWellN']
```

---

*edit 1*

If you are using a file that will easily fit in memory:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    txt=f.read()
    for m in re.finditer(r'^PATTERN1\s*(.*?)(?=^PATTERN2)', txt, re.M | re.S):
        print re.findall(r'(^\w+)', m.group(1), re.M)
```

Use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) for larger files that won't easily fit in memory.

---

*edit 2*

Just append the results to a list after joining together into a string:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    results=[]
    txt=f.read()
    for m in re.finditer(r'^PATTERN1\s*(.*?)(?=^PATTERN2)', txt, re.M | re.S):
        results.append('\n'.join(re.findall(r'(^\w+)', m.group(1), re.M))
    print '\n===\n'.join(results)
```

Comment: thanks , however my input text can vary and therefore i will have to use file = open()

Comment: You can do this same thing with file open. Just read the contents of the file into a string. I just used the `txt` string as an example.

Comment: thanks , it worked! One last question , I would like to return the final output. What is the best to return the matched expression as a list or string ? Please comment

Comment: What do you mean by *return the final output*?

Comment: Instead of print re.findall() , i need to return this to the caller.

Comment: Use `return xxx` where xxx is what you want to return. You probably need to spend time with a Python tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'PATTERN1(.*?)PATTERN2', content, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for match in matches:
    for line in match.split('\n'):
        columns = line.split()
        if columns:
            print(columns[0])
```

Comment: thanks but your function returns all the text between pattern1 <=> pattern2.